# Exact same MYSQL query but different results on different servers

Tags: mysql

I have this query.

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM private_messages ORDER BY id DESC) a
```

The "DESC" works on my local server but doesn't work on another server.
However if i just write it like this:

```
SELECT * FROM private_messages ORDER BY id DESC
```

it works on both servers. What would cause this?

Comment: Newer MySQL versions might ignore `ORDER BY` in subqueries.

Comment: Wow. Is it a bug? What can i do then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is going to be too long for a comment..

It's not a bug. It's documented [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/subquery-optimization.html):

> As of MySQL 5.7.6, the optimizer handles propagation of an ORDER BY
>   clause in a derived table or view reference to the outer query block
>   by propagating the ORDER BY clause if the following conditions apply:
>   The outer query is not grouped or aggregated; does not specify
>   DISTINCT, HAVING, or ORDER BY; and has this derived table or view
>   reference as the only source in the FROM clause. Otherwise, the
>   optimizer ignores the ORDER BY clause. Before MySQL 5.7.6, the
>   optimizer always propagated ORDER BY, even if it was irrelevant or
>   resulted in an invalid query.

However it's not the case for your query. So i guess your second server is running MariaDB which seams to ingnore any `ORDER BY` in a subquery without `LIMIT`

> A "table" (and subquery in the FROM clause too) is - according to the
>   SQL standard - an unordered set of rows. Rows in a table (or in a
>   subquery in the FROM clause) do not come in any specific order. That's
>   why the optimizer can ignore the ORDER BY clause that you have
>   specified. In fact, SQL standard does not even allow the ORDER BY
>   clause to appear in this subquery (we allow it, because ORDER BY ...
>   LIMIT ... changes the result, the set of rows, not only their order).
>
> You need to treat the subquery in the FROM clause, as a set of rows in
>   some unspecified and undefined order, and put the ORDER BY on the
>   top-level SELECT.

[Why is ORDER BY in a FROM Subquery Ignored?](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/why-is-order-by-in-a-from-subquery-ignored/)

So best you can do is just to move the `ORDER BY` clause to the outer query. Or don't use a subquery at all.

Comment: Thanks. But the query is part of a larger more complex query. And yes, it's MariaDB. I think i'll just use the `LIMIT`.

Comment: @babyleans Are you trying to calculate something like row number or rank?

Comment: I'm trying to `order by` and `group by` at the same time.

Comment: @babyleans this as an outdated "trick" and might not work for other reasons in future versions even with LIMIT. If you want to select the "most recent row per group" - there are other ways which are usually also faster (like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745609/sql-select-only-rows-with-max-value-on-a-column?rq=1)).

Comment: Thank you. i used self join. I finally got it to work!